# How can I swap a Motion Graphic Template (mogrt) in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

How can I swap a motion graphic template (essential graphics) with another one within Adobe Premiere ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If Mogrt are built similarly (same text layers etc.) drag and drop new mogrt on old holding ‘alt’.

I hope that it is what you were looking for.